# how to insert multiple records in single table using hibernate without using looping statement

Tags: hibernate

How to insert multiple records in single table using hibernate without using looping statement

When I am trying to insert multiple record in a single table using hibernate merge I am getting only one record insert. What is the solution to insert multiple record?

Comment: Actually, now when I have posted the answer, I figured I misread your question. Can you provide your loop code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to realize, that multiple `em.insert()` calls do not need to result into multiple SQL queries.

## Hibernate 3.x and higher

To enable batch inserts, certain configuration constraints apply:

1. Set `hibernate.jdbc.batch_size` to an integer between 10 and 50. That enables JDBC batching. Technically it then works so, that your inserts/merges are translated into batch inserts instead of individual ones.
2. Set `hibernate.order_inserts` and `hibernate.order_updates` to `true`. That helps with batching when you use cascading.
3. Ensure you don't use IDENTITY identifier generator on your entity IDs. That disables batch inserts for good.

More information on Hibernate performance can be found on this [blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/) by the great Vlad Mihalcea.

## Hibernate 5.2 and higher

Hibernate 5.2 allows configuration of batch size directly on persistence context level:

`entityManager.setJdbcBatchSize(10);`

Again, more details on Vlad's [blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-customize-the-jdbc-batch-size-for-each-persistence-context-with-hibernate/).